# RDS postgres - replicate a partitioned table to another RDS postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, database-replication, postgres-10

I have a partitioned table in RDS1 (version 10) that I want to replicate to another RDS postgres (version10)

I'd like to know if it's possible. If yes, what would be the method that I should apply ?

The data should be replicated in real-time, very low latency. Partitions in the master are added and removed in daily basis.

The motivation for the replication is to reduce load from the master db.

Thanks!

Comment: Not on version 10, you would need to look at v13 onwards.

Comment: thanks @VynlJunkie 
looks like v13 indeed supports this feature.//